# Generating secret tenant for Salesforce Shield encryption module using Openssl, BYOK

Tags: encryption, openssl, salesforce

Our customer needs us to implement the Shield encryption module for Salesforce, with the Bring Your Own key feature.

Our customer also provided an example of secret tenant to be integrated in Shield.
This tenant is a 32 or 64-character (letters and numbers only) chain.

Salesforce provides a script to generate our own files if we don't want to use the native ones. Here is the script :

```
#!/bin/sh

PLAINTEXT_SECRET_HASH_B64="plaintext_secret_hash.b64"
ENCRYPTED_SECRET_B64="encrypted_secret.b64"
PLAINTEXT_SECRET="plaintext_secret.bin"
PUBLIC_KEY_PEM="public_key.pem"

usage ()
{
echo 'Generates a random 256-bit value, hashes it, and encrypts it using a given certificate.'
echo ''
echo 'Usage : secretgen <downloaded.crt>'
exit
}

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
usage
fi

# generate a random value to use as the secret.
head -c 32 /dev/urandom | tr '\n' = > $PLAINTEXT_SECRET

# hash the plaintext secret and encode it with base64.  Salesforce will use this for integrity checking.
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary $PLAINTEXT_SECRET | openssl base64 -out $PLAINTEXT_SECRET_HASH_B64

# extract the public key from the downloaded .crt file
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in $1 > $PUBLIC_KEY_PEM

# encrypt the secret using the public key and encode it with base64.
openssl rsautl -oaep -encrypt -pubin -inkey $PUBLIC_KEY_PEM -in $PLAINTEXT_SECRET | openssl base64 -out $ENCRYPTED_SECRET_B64


echo 'Generated files: '$ENCRYPTED_SECRET_B64' and '$PLAINTEXT_SECRET_HASH_B64'.'
echo 'Both of these should be uploaded to Salesforce.'
```

The thing is that I would like to directly use the 32-character chain provided by our customer instead of the one generated during this step :

```
# generate a random value to use as the secret.
head -c 32 /dev/urandom | tr '\n' = > $PLAINTEXT_SECRET
```

So I tried to directly replace the generated chain with the one provided, but it simply doen't work and gives me an error messsage when all the files are uploaded in Salesforce.
I don't understand why the 32-characters chain provided by the customer won't work while a randomly generated 32-characters chain works.

Is the randomly generated chain not so random ? (it looks like a mix of letters, numbers and special characters, while the customer chain only contains numbers and letters).

Any Ideas ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Randomly generated bytes need not to map to characters. We cannot see what goes wrong, so we cannot solve this for you even if we wanted to. This is not a question, it is a request to debug your application and therefore off topic.

Comment: Ok so if I understand what you say, dev/urandom will not generate letters and numbers, just bytes ? Is that right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you print them out it will show garbage. Depending on the *assumed* character encoding and filters in the terminal window it may still be relatively readable, but don't forget that you're looking at a view that is already missing unprintable characters. In old code the output was generally considered in full, including any control sequences that messed up the character set of, say, a VT100 terminal window.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, things are much more clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

Just assumptions, depending on your OS and/or openssl tool you are using, a few things may happen:

1. your new file (**plaintext_secret.bin**) is not actually 32 bytes
2. there may be hidden space chars (line the '\n', tabs..), and your version of openssl is not handling that properly. 
   This is why there are actually 2 versions of the script, Unix and OSX
3. all is good, but you may have mixed up the certificates (BYOK needs a certificate to wrap your content)
4. the certificate needs to be a PE certificate - check it on the BYOK page.

Comment: Below is some Python code that does the same, but gives you more control when running interactively. Make sure you install the required modules.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I'm currently on holidays and will check your points and codes when I'm back in office. I dubble checked that I did choose the right certificate and that it was properly generated. I did run the script by installing Ubuntu on my windows 10 computer. I will tell you asap if it works

Answer (score 1):

```
from M2Crypto import RSA, X509
x509 = X509.load_cert("your_cert.pem")
rsa = x509.get_pubkey().get_rsa()

# building a secret as a 32bytes bytearray
my_secret = "This is my secret, and nobody knows it"
my_secret_bin = bytearray(my_secret)
# this should be exactly 32
len(my_secret_bin)

import base64
import hashlib

my_hash = base64.b64encode((hashlib.sha256(my_secret_bin[0:32])).digest())              
my_encrypted_secret = base64.b64encode(rsa.public_encrypt(my_secret_bin[0:32], RSA.pkcs1_oaep_padding))    

# This can be used to call it via API
# note that the 'your_cert' certificate name should match
upload_params = { 'SecretValue':my_encrypted_secret, 'SecretValueHash':my_hash, 'SecretValueCertificate':'your_cert'}


# write to files
with open('encrypted_secret.bb64', 'wb') as f:
f.write(my_encrypted_secret)

with open('secret_hash.b64', 'wb') as f:
f.write(my_hash)
```

Comment: Here is some Python code that does the same, but gives you more control when running interactively. Make sure you install the required modules.